# Force GCC to use repeat prefix in memset() call

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm developing an application where performance is critical. I want GCC to translate some specific calls to memset() as an instruction with a repeat prefix like "rep stos QWORD PTR es:[rdi],rax". GCC does this automatically when the size is both known and small.

However, GCC maps calls to memset() with a random length through a call to memset() via the PLT, which causes a branch misprediction since the branch predictor cache is cold.

Is there a way to force GCC to do what I want (outside of inline assembly)? Note that I don't want this behavior for the whole program, only for some specific memset() calls.

On a related topic, I'm also interested for any hack that prevents GCC from branching when a cmovcc instruction would do the job (I know about using &,+,etc. instead of &&).

Thanks a lot for any help.


@FrankH:

That's basically what I ended up doing. Here is my code:

```
static finline void app_zero(void *dst, uint32_t size, uint32_t count)
{
    // Warning: we tell gcc to use 'dst' both as source and destination here.  
    // This does not cause problems because we don't reuse 'dst'.  
    #ifdef APP_ARCH_X86 
    #define STOS(X,Y) do { \  
        int c = (size/Y)*count; \  
        __asm__ __volatile__("cld; xor %%eax, %%eax; rep stos"X"\n\n" \
                             : "+D"(dst), "+c"(c) :: "rax", "flags"); \  
        } while (0)  
    if (size % 8 == 0)      STOS("q", 8);  
    else if (size % 4 == 0) STOS("l", 4);  
    else if (size % 2 == 0) STOS("w", 2);  
    else                    STOS("b", 1);  
    #undef STOS  
    #else  
    memset(dst, 0, size*count);  
    #endif  
}
```

Note that your example works in your test setup, but it won't work
generally. GCC can change the direction flag, so a `cld` instruction is
necessary. Furthermore, you must tell gcc that `%rdi` and `%rcx` will be
changed by the `stos` instruction, and since gcc won't allow you to
specify that a register is both an input and clobbered, you must use the
awkward `"+"` syntax (which will also corrupt your input values).

This is not optimal due to the 'cld' instruction, which has a latency of
4 cycles on Nehalem. GCC tracks the flag register state internally
(AFAICT) so it needs not issue that instruction every time.

Comment: The only way I can think of to even attempt achieving something which applies only to certain parts of the code would be GCC's attributes(function, variable and type attributes). However, at a quick glance none of them achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I confirm that no such attribute/pragma seems to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about GCC, but under newer builds of MSVC, using loops to do the setting/copying forced the used of `REP STOS` (and it still allows optimization for know sizes and auto-vectorization), it may be work a try under GCC.

the alternative to to check if GCC has a builtin similar to `__stosq`, else you will probably need to go down to inline assembly, but thats not bad at all under GCC (and its probably the simplest and fastest way).

your second question is way to generic to really get a good answer, cause it depends on the case at hand, however, GCC should do well enough in optimizing out branches except for specific corner cases (using `SETCC`/`MOVCC`/`FMOVCC`).

Comment: I've tried using a simple loop to do the memset(). No luck, gcc still insists on using branches. I'm now using inline assembly wrappers around `stos` and `movs`. This is far from optimal since I have to insert a `cld` instruction in case gcc set the direction flag. 

As for optimizing out branches, my experience has been that GCC loves to use branches even for simple cases like `MIN` and `MAX`. Using inline assembly for those cases is not optimal since it constraints the register usage of the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to force this, why *exclude* inline assembly as an option ?

```
#define my_forced_inline_memset(dst, c, N) \
   __asm__ __volatile__(                   \
       "rep stosq %%rax, (%%rdi)\n\t"
       : : "D"((dst)), "a"((c)), "c"((N)) : "memory");
```

Using this in a demo program like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    my_forced_inline_memset(argv[0], 0, argc);
    return 0;
}
```

creates me this assembly:

```
00000000004004b0 <main>:
  4004b0:       89 f9                   mov    %edi,%ecx
  4004b2:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4004b4:       48 8b 3e                mov    (%rsi),%rdi
  4004b7:       f3 ab                   repz stos %rax,%es:(%rdi)
  4004b9:       c3                      retq
```

That's not an explanation why GCC chooses to do differently, but as said if you want to force the behaviour you can, and if you explicitly know the place(s) where you need this then there's little wrong with calling some sort of specially-defined memset of your own ?

**Note:** `repz stos %rax,(%rdi)` (or the Intel syntax `QWORD PTR` equiv) is *not* the same as `memset()` because the granularity for `memset()` is a single byte. The above is rather the same as `memset(..., c, N * 8)` because of that. Keep this in mind.

*Edit:* If you write the code as:

```
#include <stdint.h>                        // for uintptr_t
#define my_forced_inline_memset(dst, c, N)                            \
   __asm__ __volatile__(                                              \
       "rep stos %1, (%0)\n\t"                                        \
       :: "D"((dst)), "a"((uintptr_t)(c)), "c"((N)/sizeof(uintptr_t)) \
       : "memory");
```

it compiles both for 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: Regarding the direction flag and the ABI, there's a long and winding discussion about this on the gcc mailing list, http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2008-03/msg00330.html - that message implies that the compiler will _assure_ `DF=0` before inline assembly, i.e. it shouldn't ever be necessary to explicitly do `cld`, gcc supposedly does it for you if needed. Also, re the branch misprediction due to the PLT use, couldn't you work around that by calling `memset()` through a function pointer ?

Comment: Should've added: https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/3/5/306 is the Linux kernel fix for the incorrect `DF` values the gcc mailing list thread talks about. It also mentions the ABI requirement on `DF=0` before function calls. The gcc thread, in another one of its numerous messages, also states that `memmove()` might `std` but is guaranteed to do `cld` before return.

Comment: About the branch misprediction stuff: unless I'm very mistaken, any taken branch (even an unconditional jump where the address is hard-coded in the instruction) will result in a branch misprediction (i.e. pipeline stall) if the branch target is not in the branch prediction cache. This will be the case in my code since the working set does not fit in the cache.

Comment: About the direction flag: my inline assembly version of memset() changes the program behavior unless I insert a CLD instruction. So either my implementation is subtly wrong and the presence of the CLD instruction causes gcc to reorganize the code and mask the problem, or the instruction is actually necessary for some reason.

Comment: gcc does not analyze the contents of an inline assembly section, i.e. it will not know/recognize you've got a `cld` there. But the `"flags"` clobber will tell gcc that coming _out_ of the `asm` section, it shouldn't rely on previous flag state (and that includes `DF`). The difference is / would be the presence of `"flags"` in the clobber list, not the presence of `cld` _inside_ the `asm` block contents.

Comment: You are probably right about the `DF` semantics. My code changed and I can't reproduce the problem with or without the `cld` instruction and/or the `flags` keyword, which leads me to suspect the problem might not be with this function. I'll let you know if I find eventually find out the `cld` instruction is necessary. Thanks for the help.